# Will 2 spark application cause any in consistency

Tags: apache-spark, hive-metastore

Will 2 spark application cause any in consistency

I have 2 spark application. One is writing the data through Hive Metastore as below:

```
df.write
  .option("path", "adl:///test-data/hive_tables")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .format("json")
  .partitionBy("col1")
  .saveAsTable("sample")
```

While other is reading the data from same table as below:

```
spark.read.table("sample")
```

If both jobs are running in parallel, is there any possibility that the data read by second application will be inconsistent? If so, how can I avoid it

Comment: It will be definitely be inconsistent. You can look into the `delta` file format (site: https://delta.io/) which aims to provide transactional guarantees.